# Debugging in PyCharm using existing console variables

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am working in PyCharm with a large amount of data and attempting to debug various processing functions which act upon objects assembled using those data. Since a new debug does not bring console-stored variables with it, I am finding it necessary to slowly re-load the data on each debug. So far I have used *pickle* to save the objects and then re-load them more quickly, but this is still not ideal.

Is there a way to work in a console with loaded data and when necessary begin a debug session which starts out with the previously loaded data variables from that console?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the PyCharm debugger? Have you considered using `pdb`? This is built into all python installations. It is a command-line debugger, and is intimidating if you aren't used to that, but it's actually very simple. Because it runs on the console, any python program you can get running on the console you can get running in the debugger, no contortions required to get your code running in an IDE like PyCharm.

Ways to access it:

- Invoke your code as `python -m pdb mymodule.py`
- Run your code in the python interpreter using:

  ```
  import pdb
  import mymodule
  pdb.run('mymodule.entry_function()')
  ```
- Add the following into your code where you want to stop and look around:

  ```
  import pdb
  pdb.set_trace()
  ```

Once you're in the debugger (you'll have a command-line prompt `(pdb)`) you can use debugger commands. These include (not exhaustive, see docs for more):

- `b(reak) <line_number>` - Set a breakpoint at the specified line
- `c(ontinue)` - Run code to the next breakpoint or to the end of execution
- `n(ext)` - Execute the next line in the current function
- `s(tep)` - Execute the next line in any function (ie. follow current function call)

You can also inspect variables at any point by typing the name of the variable, and you can execute python code as if you were at the point in program execution that the program has reached.

The python docs on it are pretty good, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html